# What kind of subrings inherit their parent ring's properties?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains, integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains

I was studying the proof my teacher from my abstract algebra course gave me for the Gauss Lemma, and I came up with a question he could not answer me at that moment (it's the first time he works teaching about rings). The question goes like this:

> Consider $R$ a ring. Being $I\leq R$ a subring of $R$, which of the
> following statements is true?
>
> 1. $R$ field $\implies$ $I$ field.
> 2. $R$ euclidean domain $\implies$ $I$ euclidean domain.
> 3. $R$ principal ideal domain $\implies$ $I$ principal ideal domain.
> 4. $R$ Unique factorisation domain $\implies$ $I$ Unique factorisation domain.
> 5. $R$ integral domain domain $\implies$ $I$ integral domain.

I don't know if these are just dumb questions, I'm a bit new to abstract algebra and all these definitions of rings tend to confuse me. Is any of the above statements true? Is any of them true for $I$ ideal subring of $R$? Can you give counterexamples for those false? Is any true is I use the word "ring" instead of "domain"?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: A good source for counterexamples here would be to take suitable integral domains $I$ and set $R$ to be the fraction field of $I$.

Comment: @leoli1 Oh, you're right. So that proves statement 1 isn't true. Thanks!

Comment: Fields do not have any ideals (well any ideals worth mentioning that is). The only ideals of a field are the 0 ideal and the field itself. The 0 ideal is not a field so 1 is false indeed.

Comment: 5 is true. Consider if there exists elements $x, y \in I \implies x, y \in R$ such that $xy = 0 \in I$. But then $xy = 0 \in R$, which is a contradiction since $R$ is an integral domain.